# Python: random number game with input validation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a program that is a guessing game where the user has one chance to guess a number between 1 and 20.

There are two problems with the code:

Number one is still the input validation.  The `firstGuess` variable is actually in `main()`.

```
firstGuess = userguess()    
def userGuess():
    while True:
        try:
            guess = int(input('Enter a number between 1 and 20: '))
            if 1 <= guess >= 20:
                return guess
        except ValueError:
            print (guess, 'is not a valid guess!')
        break
```

What I'm trying to do is put the input validation in a loop (while True:) until the user gives good input (in this case a positive number between 1 and 20). If the user were to enter 'd', or '-5', the program *should* continue looping until good input is given. However, this is not the case. By adjusting the code, I have been able to ask for the input again once bad input is entered, but if bad input is given a third time I get "another exception occured while handling this exception."

*Removed other problem, @Henry Woody was correct in that I wasn't using the conditionals correctly.

Comment: Condition not quite right. Use `if 1 <= guess <= 20:`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: Played with code just a *bit* more and got it working, the sense of relief I feel is immense, and wouldn't have been possible without the help I got here,  thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues are with the conditionals.

The first is the line:

```
if 1 <= guess >= 20:
```

in `userGuess`, which is checking for a number greater than or equal to 20, which is not what you want. You can fix this issue by changing the condition to:

```
if 1 <= guess <= 20:
```

Next, the conditional:

```
if guess1 == randomOne or randomTwo or randomThree:
```

checks whether `guess1 == randomOne` or if `randomTwo` is truthy or if `randomThree` is truthy. It does not check if `guess1 == randomOne` or `guess1 == randomTwo` or `guess1 == randomThree` as intended. You can fix this by changing the condition to:

```
if guess1 in [randomOne, randomTwo, randomThree]:
```

to check if `guess1` is equal to either of the three random variables.

**Edit:**

There is also an issue in the `try`/`except` block. If the user enters a non-digit character in the `input`, a `ValueError` will be raised before `guess` is defined. But then `guess` is referenced in the `except` block, but `guess` isn't defined at that point.

You can fix this by getting the user input and then, separately, trying to convert the input to an `int`.

Here's an example:

```
while True:
    guess = input('Enter a number between 1 and 20: ')
    try:
        guess = int(guess)
        if 1 <= guess <= 20:
            return guess
    except ValueError:
        print (guess, 'is not a valid guess!')
    break
```

Comment: I see the problem with the conditionals, I'm always mixing up my greater than's/less than's for some reason (should be relatively simple, think of pac man, that's how it was explained to me years back). The input validation is still a pain, though, what's wrong with my while true: block?